# Pandas Check if all Dates are Equal

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking at the `df.eq()` function to check if all my dates are equal.

How would it be applied here?

I need to check that all the `df.date` values are equal.

```
       id        date   value   ...      
0       1  2016-04-30  244793   ...        
1       2  2016-04-29  244685   ...   
2       4  2016-04-30  453193   ...
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: just True or False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need compare by first value with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) for check all `True`s:

```
out = df['date'].eq(df['date'].iat[0]).all()
```

Numpy solution:

```
arr = df['date']
out = np.all(arr == arr[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count unique values and check if it is more than one or not

```
df.agg({'date': pd.Series.nunique}) == 1
```